# Apple push notification for non english message in erlang/ejabberd

Tags: erlang, apple-push-notifications, ejabberd

I am not getting the correct order of the message if I set the language to non-english. The non-english words are coming ok, but not in correct order.
Please help and suggest if I have to additional to get the proper order.

The code snippet is as below:

```
send_ios_msg(Token,Badge1,Type,Msg,ENUM,Groupid,Groupname,Sender_list_without_resource,Content_list,Socket) ->

  Msg_final =list_to_binary(Msg),

  Msg_final_binarytolist = binary_to_list(Msg_final),

  %%Preparing Payload
  Payload = mochijson:encode({struct,[{"aps", {struct, [{"alert", Msg_final},{"content-available",Badge1}]}}, {"acme1", Type},{"acme2", Msg}, {"acme3", ENUM},{"acme4", Groupid}, {"acme5", Groupname},{"acme6", Sender_list_without_resource}, {"acme7", Content_list}]}),

  %%Converting Payload to binary
  BPayload = erlang:list_to_binary(Payload),  

  %%Fetching length of payload
  PayloadLen = erlang:byte_size(BPayload),

  %%Converting hexadecimal token to binary
  BToken = hexstr_to_bin(Token),

  %%Fetching length of token
  BTokenLength = erlang:byte_size(BToken),
  SomeID= 1,

  %%time stamp
  {MSeconds,Seconds,_} = erlang:now(),
  Expiry = MSeconds * 1000000 + Seconds + 3600*1,

  %%Constructing APNS packet
  Packet = <<1:8, SomeID:32/big, Expiry:32/big, BTokenLength:16/big, BToken/binary, PayloadLen:16/big, BPayload/binary>>,

  %Sending data over SSL
  ssl:send(Socket, Packet).
```

Comment: We need more details to be able to help you. Do you have example code ? Which push module / service are you using ?

Comment: The code snippet is added.

Comment: The actual problem that you're having is with right-to-left or bidirectional text. You should begin by using some APNS test application to send yourself push messages and figure out what data you need to send. The fact that you're sending the pushes from within ejabberd does not matter -- it's just a question of the data that you're sending.